# MSVC Find where a symbol is coming from

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Situation:

- I am using CI to compile a Windows version of my project using CMake and MSVC
- It errors out right at the end complaining of two missing symbols (`__std_system_error_allocate_message` and `__std_system_error_deallocate_message`)
- When I replicate the build process on my own computer, the build finishes fine and the artifacts run without errors.
- Searching for these symbols on Google yields no clues as to which libraries they are supposed to be defined in.

Which leads to my question:

- Is it possible to see where the MSVC linker is finding a particular symbol?
- I was able to find instructions to look at what symbols are defined in a particular library, but this project is linking dozens of libraries, and the ones I have searched so far do not define the symbol. I think this approach is prone to errors as I might miss a library without knowing it.

Comment: They are internal symbols from the MSVC Stardard Library implementation ( https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/457/files ) .  Check you have the same tool-kits on both computers. And that the work-in-progress STL from GitHub is not being used.

Comment: @RichardCritten I had encountered that page but didn't realize it was part of the standard library. I would have thought the project would be named msvcrt or something similar. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Consider the initials of the guy doing the project management - Stephan T Lavavej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Richard Critten pointed me on the right path, the problem was due to having different versions of the MSVC toolchain on each system. GitLab's CI runners were [using build tools version 16.2.3.0](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/ci-cd/shared-runners/images/gcp/windows-containers/blob/master/cookbooks/preinstalled-software/README.md) while I was using a more recent 16.6.1.0. Uninstalling that and installing 16.2.3 from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history) reproduced the error. Recompiling a dependency I had previously compiled with the newer toolchain then resolved the error on both systems.